# SyntaxError: Unexpected token import error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browserify, babeljs

I am getting "Unexpected token import" when trying to run my react app

error that I am getting

```
  User:my-version username$ node build
  User:my-version username$ node app.js 
  /Users/Hindreen/Documents/workspace/apps/test/app.js:1
  (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import React 
  from 'react';
                                                          ^^^^^^

  SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
      at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
      at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
      at Module._compile (module.js:588:28)
      at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:635:10)
      at Module.load (module.js:545:32)
      at tryModuleLoad (module.js:508:12)
      at Function.Module._load (module.js:500:3)
      at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:665:10)
      at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
      at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
  User:test username$
```

app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Application extends React.Component {
 render() {
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <h1>Hello From React</h1>
       </div>
    );
  }
 }
```

build.js

```
 var fs = require("fs");
 var browserify = require("browserify");
 var babelify = require("babelify");
 browserify({ debug: true })
  .transform(babelify)
  .require("./app.js", { entry: true })
  .bundle()
  .on("error", function (err) { console.log("Error: " + err.message); })
  .pipe(fs.createWriteStream("bundle.js"));
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["env", "react"],
  "plugins": ["transform-es2015-modules-amd"]
}
```

package.json  devDependencies

```
{
 "devDependencies":{
  "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-amd": "^6.24.1",
  "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
  "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
  "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
  "babelify": "^7.3.0",
  "browserify": "^13.3.0",
  "react": "^15.0.2",
  "react-dom": "^15.0.2"
 }
}
```

I appreciate any help, Thanks in advance and please let me know if my question is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
const React = require('react'),
      ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
```

if you write in ES6-syntax => install and use babel

Answer (score 0):

`-> User:my-version username$ node app.js`

Unless you want to run your code server side, this is not the appropriate way to bootstrapping your 'build' code.

Please refer to the following which mimics your setup: https://repl.it/repls/RemoteJovialSignature
(*it doesn't actually run, it's only for viewing purposes*).

Steps to run locally:

- `node build` - builds the bundle.js
- Open `index.html` in your browser

Answer (score 0):

I just solved saving my script file `text.js` back to UTF from Unicode. Probably the single-quote (') in Unicode was not recognized.
It was failing in line

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
```